# How does the method reference resolve in Java

Tags: java, method-reference

```
Function<String, Integer> f = Integer::new;

Integer i = f.apply("100");
```

How this turns to use `Integer.parseInt` when we are calling `f.apply`?

Comment: `new Integer(String)` invokes `Integer#parseInt`; that's why

Comment: @CuriousDev You might want to at least restore an edit that makes the buik of the code *code*. The type parameterisation is being interpreted as bad HTML.

Comment: Thanks for corrections , and please upvote , so that i can fully use stackoverflow.This is awesome place to discuss things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I surmise that your question is: "How does javac know to invoke parseInt here"?

Your snippet is broken; the generics fell off. As is, your code won't compile, as the reference is ambiguous. If you add it back in, it will compile and works as normal:

```java
Function<String, Integer> f = Integer::new;
Integer i = f.apply("100");
```

Forget the new `::` syntax or the `Function` part; they are red herrings.

So let's make it simpler:

`Integer i = new Integer("100");`

That is valid java; i will end up holding the value 100.

It works because... that constructor exists. It is specced to act precisely as `Integer.parseInt` with a radix of 10 works, and it is deprecated, for 2 good reasons: [A] invoking `new Integer()` at all, with any value, is deprecated (use `Integer.valueOf`), and [B] just call parseInt.

Comment: Thanks , to understand my concern, all i get it now that using Interger::new (new Interger(String)) returns the Interger instance and thats what apply returns back , isn't it ? Please confirm

Answer (score 1):

<s>First off, that's not a method reference, it's a lambda.</s>

What you might mean to do is `Function<String, Integer> f = Integer::parseInt`.

The Java compiler turns that lambda expression into a `Function` object where the `apply` method is overriden by what's in the lambda. Lambda expressions are basically syntactic sugar that you use to create instances of interfaces that only have one method (they're called functional interfaces). For all intents and purposes that lambda gets expanded to:

```
class FunctionImpl extends Function<String, Integer> {
  @Override
  public Integer apply(String s) {
    return new Integer(s); //which calls Integer.parseInt(s) internally
  }
}
Function f = new FunctionImpl();
```

However, in the actual bytecode, there's a new method generated and a special opcode called invokevirtual that calls that method.

Comment: Thanks, but my main question was around this thing  Function f = Integer::new; . so how this automatically uses the Interger.parseInt , just because it matches the context of apply method from Function

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Internally ```new Integer(s)``` calls ```Integer.parseInt(s)```. It's nothing special, just look at the source.

Answer (score -1):

`apply` comes from Java 8's [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) class.

> R apply(T t)
>
> Applies this function to the given argument.
>
> Parameters:
>      t - the function argument
>   Returns:
>      the function result